# Xcode - can you force the Display Zoom to Standard?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

Have an app approved for TestFlight then realised when the Settings/Display & Brightness/Display Zoom was set to Zoom the screens displayed oversized, as shown below.

[image]

Standard

[image]

Zoomed

Is there a way to keep your App in Standard mode?
If not, what is your advice to rectify this?

I can test for the setting with the following code:

```
    public static var isZoomed: Bool {
    return UIScreen.main.scale < UIScreen.main.nativeScale
    }
```

Comment: TBH it doesn't look that bad, them tab bar items. The button though - maybe you should fiddle with the constraints a tad, like, limit the leading/trailing insets.

Comment: Thanks :-). The tab bar, for example, grows from 48 pixels (standard) to 55 (zoom). So the screens, which are tight already will be hard if I have to rework the Auto Layout. Hence the original question.